# Finding only records with numbers in a character string field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, query, string

I need to isolate those records containing numbers from a field with character string (it's a descriptive field). For example the string might be as follows:

> "A residential development of 12 no. two storey dwellings comprising
>   10 no. 4 bedroom semi-detached houses and 2 no. detached 3 bedroom
>   houses all with associated on-curtilage parking."

Table name: `PLANAPP_iPlan_Merged`

Field Name: `Description`

The numbers can occur anywhere in the string so I can't set `Left%`/ `Right$` parameters. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is for MapInfo Professional but there should be a similar method possible in ArcGIS.

You can do this using the following SQL query. It checks whether each numeric digit exists in the string and returns its position if it does and 0 if it is not found. If any exist then the result of the addition should be greater than 0.

```
SELECT * 
FROM PLANAPP_iPlan_Merged 
WHERE (InStr(1,Description,"0") + InStr(1,Description,"1") + 
       InStr(1,Description,"2") + InStr(1,Description,"3") + 
       InStr(1,Description,"4") + InStr(1,Description,"5") + 
       InStr(1,Description,"6") + InStr(1,Description,"7") + 
       InStr(1,Description,"8") + InStr(1,Description,"9")) > 0
```

Comment: That is amazing!! You're a pure legend - thank you - worked like a dream :)

Comment: @IreneD'Arcy Great, glad to help! Can you be a legend yourself and mark it as the accepted answer please? :-)

Comment: Neat solution, @T_Bacon!

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS you can use the Field Calculator. Add a new field with data type Short and calculate. You can then use this field to select all rows with numbers:

[image]

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
```

And below (replace String with the name of your field):

```
hasNumbers(!String!)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - we're hoping to move to Arc later this year so this will be great to have!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list of all the numbers as they are in the description field. add a new field of type `Text`, and in the `Field calculator` do the following after selecting `Python parser`:

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def get_num(field):
    number = [str(s) for s in field.split() if s.isdigit()]
    return str(number)
```

Write under the New_Field =

```
get_num(!Decr!)  #Change !Decr! with !Description! in your case
```

The result will be as follows:

```
['12', '10', '4', '2', '3']
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Python, you can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and a [Search Cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) to extract integers from a string:

```
import arcpy, re

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\fc'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "some_field") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0]
        print re.findall('\d+', row[0])
```